# All Rails Flash Messages are shown in green

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whether it's `flash[:notice]` or `flash[:warning]`, all my flash messages are shown in green. And I know why

```
<% flash.each do |flash, message| %>

  <div class = "alert alert-success" <%= flash %>>
    <%= message %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

How can I refactor this code, so the class is `alert-flash-level`

I think you can use String Interpolation but I'm not sure.

Comment: `.alert-success` in rails `css` set to green color. You can investigate with in your browser's debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% flash.each do |flash_level, message| %>

  <div class = "alert alert-<%= flash_level %>">
    <%= message %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. In ERB files, you need to put ruby inside braces, you can't use string interpolation

Comment: @DarkMouse - you are right, I corrected the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<% flash.each do |flash_level, message| %>

  <div class = "alert alert-<%= message.include?('wrong') ? "danger" : "success" %>">
    <%= message %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

The above style of code is `Embedded Ruby`. You can't use String Interpolation in ERB. Instead, you have to declare ruby code using `<%=` and `%>